# Concurrent collection size calculation

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

The documentation of most collections in the Java standard library such as [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), [ConcurrentLinkedDequeue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) come with the following disclaimer:

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is not a
>   constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these
>   sets, determining the current number of elements requires a traversal
>   of the elements, and so may report inaccurate results if this
>   collection is modified during traversal.

What does that mean? Why can't they keep a counter (say, an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)) and just return the value on calls to `size()`?

Is it because the counter must be synchronized and therefore creates a choke point?

As a side note, [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) does not seem to have this issue. Why is that? Looking at the source code, it seems like it uses multiple counters kept in an array that are summed on calls to `size()`. Is that to circumvent the choke point or is there another reason?

Comment: an atomic counter would definitely be bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a shared resource to maintain the size() would be both expensive and rather useless.  `size()` is likely to be incorrect as soon as it returns as you cannot hold a lock on the collection so it can change between you calling it and when you get the value.

ConcurentHashMap has the same approach.  The size() can be incorrect before the method has returned.

Comment: Of course `size()` can't be fully trusted, I accept that. But the problem I have is the non-constant cost of traversing every element in the collection to count them. But I guess I was right about the choke-point then?

Comment: @GustavKarlsson Peter's first sentence really addresses the reason.  Synchronization and cache invalidation would be very costly for a queue to operate. Yes, you were right, there would certainly be a bottle neck there.  That is one of the main issues with `ReentrantReadWriteLock`